# What is the point of Jest's createTransformer method in its *Transformer interface?

Tags: jestjs

I have been looking into/debugging [code transformation](https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation) related issues in Jest for the last day and a recurring theme is that the `SyncTransformer#createTransformer` method is a constant source of surprise and it is not really documented why it exists.

The `SyncTransformer` interface only has a single field one has to implement: `process`. But it seems that if one implements `createTransformer` those other methods will not be used: instead Jest seems to create a new transformer using `createTransformer`, which caused me to lose a few hairs until I figured what was going on. This behaviour is [not documented](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/v27.5.1/packages/jest-transform/src/types.ts#L79) either.

[The `babel-jest` source](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/v27.5.1/packages/babel-jest/src/index.ts#L152) for Jest 27.

Answer (score 0):

I filed [a documentation bug issue with Jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/12403) after I could see that the behavior was not mirrored in the docs, which I subsequently [fixed](https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/12407) by updating the types and docs for code transformation.

The rules for this is basically like follows:

- if `createTransformer` exists as an export, then `jest-transform` will use that to create a transformer dynamically and not use any of the other exports
- if the transformer is imported using `import` (and not `require`) it will try to use `processAsync` and fall back to `process` if the async version does not exist